# angular 14 "ng lint" command is not working how to run the command

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, lint, angular14

when ever I hit this command "ng lint" I get the following error: `Cannot find "lint" target fo the specified project. You can add a package that implements these capabilities.`.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XkN8.png)
After adding the `@angular-eslint/schematics`, I tried the `ng lint` command again, but the result stays the same.

Package.json

```json
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "ng build",
        "build:app": "ng build xyz --configuration production",
        "doc:app": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -t --hideGenerator -d \"dist/docs/app\"",
        "e2e": "ng e2e pjms-admin-e2e --webdriver-update=false",
        "e2e:ci": "ng e2e xyz-e2e --webdriver-update=false --protractor-config=./e2e/protractor-ci.conf.js",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "lint:app": "ng lint xyz",
        "ng": "ng",
        "postbuild:app": "npm run doc:app",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl=true --gecko false",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "start:hmr": "ng serve --port 4201 --hmr -c=hmr",
        "start:subpath": "ng serve --port 4202 --serve-path=/test/ --base-href=/test/",
        "test": "ng test"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "angular/animations": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.6",
        "@angular/common": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/core": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.40",
        "@angular/forms": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/material": "^14.2.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/router": "^14.2.8",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "core-js": "^2.6.5",
        "mat-table-exporter": "^10.2.4",
        "ngx-filesize": "^2.0.16",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/cli": "^14.2.7",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.8",
        "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.8",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
        "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.3",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "cpx": "^1.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "protractor-console-plugin": "^0.1.1",
        "puppeteer": "^1.5.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.6.4"
    }
}
```

I want use "ng lint" my application is not working

Here is my angular.json file

```
 "lint": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                "options": {
                    "tsConfig": [
                        "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                    ],
                    "exclude": [
                        "**/node_modules/**"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please include code directly in the question body, do not use images. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Make sure the eslint dependencies are actually in your `package.json`. From the image you provided there's no telling whether they're included or not.

Comment: I added package .json file entire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `angular.json` file is missing a `lint` target.

Judging by the `package.json` provided, you also did not add and execute the `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics` schematic.

Comment: I added angular.json file but still not working

Comment: `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find builder "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint".
See "C:\Users\uje2kor\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ftY8QD\angular-errors.log" for further details.`
when hit this command "ng lint"

Comment: You're trying to run tslint, which is deprecated since Angular 13. Judging from your comments, you also did not add ``@angular-eslint/schematics``.